# Issue including my correct 404.php file

Tags: php

I have a project where I have a administrative panel.

I have a website folder, inside this folder,  I have an admin and a template folder.

**Inside "Admin" folder I have:**

1 folder "news"

1 folder "categories"

1 index.php -> where I have my query string

1 folder "includes" where I have my "home.php", "header.php" and also "404.php"

**Inside template folder**, I have my website pages.

This is my **query string** that I have in my admin index.php file to do my navigation:

```
$whitelist = array('inc/home.php', 'inc/404.php', 
            'news/index.php','news/news-create.php','categories/categories-edit.php',
            'categories/categories-create.php', 
            'index.php', 'inc/header.php','inc/footer.php');

if(empty($_GET['nav'])){
    require('inc/home.php');
}
elseif(in_array($_GET['nav'].'.php', $whitelist)){
    require($_GET['nav'].'.php');
}
else{
    require('inc/404.php');
}
```

**But Im having a problem.**

If I acess an url that dont exist, for example: htp://localhost/website/admin/news/news

I want to include my 404.php file of my admin/includes foder, but Im including my 404.php file of my website folder.

I dont understand how this is possible!

But If I acess for example this url: htp://localhost/website/admin/dashboard.php?nav=errortesting,

This url also dont exist, but I get my correct 404.php file of my admin folder.

It seems that my 404.php file its only included if I have my "nav" variable.

Do you understand why this can be happening?

I have a .htaccess file inside my website folder (but Im using just for website pages purposes, and not for admin pages):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1
```

Comment: Looks like this may be a routing issue.  What does your `.htaccess` look like for your admin folder and for your home folder?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I update my question with my .htaccess file!

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your webserver (Apache,  nginx,... ) to customize the 404 error. The way you are doing this is only valid if the parameter 'nav' is empty. The 404 error comes from the webserver because no php script/file was found from the given URL

Comment: I dont know why you get a downgrade! But I vote up now, do you know how can I configure my xampp for that? But If I remove my htaccess file when I try to acess a page that dont exist, I get not my 404.php file but a default object not found page... So should be something about my htaccess!

Answer (score 0):

you should use a [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.htaccess) with following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* ./
```

this will redirect every request which adresses no file or folder to the index.php

for direct redirect to the 404-page change the last line to this:

```
RewriteRule .* ./inc/404.php
```